# Npm install fails because of mismatched dependencies. Attaching the error when I run the command npm install

Tags: npm, dependency-injection, angular-cli, npm-install, package.json

While resolving: @angular-eslint/builder@12.0.0
Found: @angular/cli@10.0.8
node_modules/@angular/cli
peer @angular/cli@"^10.0.0" from @angular-extensions/model@10.0.1
node_modules/@angular-extensions/model
@angular-extensions/model@"^10.0.1" from the root project
dev @angular/cli@"~10.0.8" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer @angular/cli@">= 12.0.0 < 13.0.0" from @angular-eslint/builder@12.0.0
node_modules/@angular-eslint/builder
dev @angular-eslint/builder@"^12.0.0" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/cli@12.2.18
node_modules/@angular/cli
peer @angular/cli@">= 12.0.0 < 13.0.0" from @angular-eslint/builder@12.0.0
node_modules/@angular-eslint/builder
dev @angular-eslint/builder@"^12.0.0" from the root project

**Raw JSON explanation object:**

```
{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "edge": {
    "type": "peer",
    "name": "@angular/cli",
    "spec": ">= 12.0.0 < 13.0.0",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "name": "@angular-eslint/builder",
      "version": "12.0.0",
      "location": "node_modules/@angular-eslint/builder",
      "isWorkspace": false,
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "dev",
          "name": "@angular-eslint/builder",
          "spec": "^12.0.0",
          "from": {
            "location": "D:\\people-care-service\\azure-repos\\app-focus-360\\master-branch-clients\\Clients"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "dep": {
    "name": "@angular/cli",
    "version": "12.2.18",
    "whileInstalling": {
      "name": "@angular-eslint/builder",
      "version": "12.0.0",
      "path": "D:\\people-care-service\\azure-repos\\app-focus-360\\master-branch-clients\\Clients\\node_modules\\@angular-eslint\\builder"
    },
    "location": "node_modules/@angular/cli",
    "isWorkspace": false,
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "peer",
        "name": "@angular/cli",
        "spec": ">= 12.0.0 < 13.0.0",
        "error": "INVALID",
        "from": {
          "name": "@angular-eslint/builder",
          "version": "12.0.0",
          "location": "node_modules/@angular-eslint/builder",
          "isWorkspace": false,
          "dependents": [
            {
              "type": "dev",
              "name": "@angular-eslint/builder",
              "spec": "^12.0.0",
              "from": {
                "location": "D:\\people-care-service\\azure-repos\\app-focus-360\\master-branch-clients\\Clients"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "current": {
    "name": "@angular/cli",
    "version": "10.0.8",
    "location": "node_modules/@angular/cli",
    "isWorkspace": false,
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "peer",
        "name": "@angular/cli",
        "spec": "^10.0.0",
        "from": {
          "name": "@angular-extensions/model",
          "version": "10.0.1",
          "location": "node_modules/@angular-extensions/model",
          "isWorkspace": false,
          "dependents": [
            {
              "type": "prod",
              "name": "@angular-extensions/model",
              "spec": "^10.0.1",
              "from": {
                "location": "D:\\people-care-service\\azure-repos\\app-focus-360\\master-branch-clients\\Clients"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "dev",
        "name": "@angular/cli",
        "spec": "~10.0.8",
        "from": {
          "location": "D:\\people-care-service\\azure-repos\\app-focus-360\\master-branch-clients\\Clients"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "peerConflict": {
    "current": {
      "name": "@angular/cli",
      "version": "10.0.8",
      "location": "node_modules/@angular/cli",
      "isWorkspace": false,
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "peer",
          "name": "@angular/cli",
          "spec": "^10.0.0",
          "from": {
            "name": "@angular-extensions/model",
            "version": "10.0.1",
            "location": "node_modules/@angular-extensions/model",
            "isWorkspace": false,
            "dependents": [
              {
                "type": "prod",
                "name": "@angular-extensions/model",
                "spec": "^10.0.1",
                "from": {
                  "location": "D:\\people-care-service\\azure-repos\\app-focus-360\\master-branch-clients\\Clients"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "dev",
          "name": "@angular/cli",
          "spec": "~10.0.8",
          "from": {
            "location": "D:\\people-care-service\\azure-repos\\app-focus-360\\master-branch-clients\\Clients"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "peer": {
      "name": "@angular/cli",
      "version": "12.2.18",
      "whileInstalling": {
        "name": "@angular-eslint/builder",
        "version": "12.0.0",
        "path": "D:\\people-care-service\\azure-repos\\app-focus-360\\master-branch-clients\\Clients\\node_modules\\@angular-eslint\\builder"
      },
      "location": "node_modules/@angular/cli",
      "isWorkspace": false,
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "peer",
          "name": "@angular/cli",
          "spec": ">= 12.0.0 < 13.0.0",
          "error": "INVALID",
          "from": {
            "name": "@angular-eslint/builder",
            "version": "12.0.0",
            "location": "node_modules/@angular-eslint/builder",
            "isWorkspace": false,
            "dependents": [
              {
                "type": "dev",
                "name": "@angular-eslint/builder",
                "spec": "^12.0.0",
                "from": {
                  "location": "D:\\people-care-service\\azure-repos\\app-focus-360\\master-branch-clients\\Clients"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false,
  "isMine": true
}
```

**I do not want to use --force, or --legacy-peer-deps command as it gives an
incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.**

**Also this is for my prod environment**

**Adding package.json as requested**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "nx": "nx",
    "heap": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096",
    "affected:apps": "nx affected:apps",
    "affected:libs": "nx affected:libs",
    "affected:build": "nx affected:build",
    "affected:e2e": "nx affected:e2e",
    "affected:test": "nx affected:test",
    "affected:lint": "nx affected:lint",
    "affected:dep-graph": "nx affected:dep-graph",
    "affected": "nx affected",
    "format": "nx format:write",
    "format:write": "nx format:write",
    "format:check": "nx format:check",
    "update": "ng update @nrwl/workspace",
    "workspace-schematic": "nx workspace-schematic",
    "dep-graph": "nx dep-graph",
    "help": "nx help",
    "start:local": "ng serve -c local",
    "start2": "ng serve --aot",
    "markup": "ng serve --port 4400 --proxy-config proxy.markup.json",
    "postinstall": "node ./decorate-angular-cli.js && ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-extensions/model": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.14",   
    "@angular/localize": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/material": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.1000.8",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~10.0.14",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.1.0",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.21.0",
    "@kolkov/ngx-gallery": "1.2.3",
    "@markpieszak/ng-application-insights": "^8.0.3",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.5.8",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^3.1.7",
    "@ngneat/until-destroy": "^8.0.2",
    "@nrwl/angular": "10.3.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.9",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.22",
    "angular-gridster2": "~10.0.1",
    "angular-maps": "^6.0.3",
    "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.21",
    "bingmaps": "^2.0.3",
    "blueimp-load-image": "^5.14.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "canvas": "^2.8.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.26.1",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "idb": "^2.1.3",
    "js-sha256": "^0.9.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mobile-detect": "^1.4.4",
    "ng-dynamic-component": "^7.0.1",
    "ngx-autosize": "^1.8.0",
    "ngx-editor": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-file-drop": "~10.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^11.1.4",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-permissions": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-pinch-zoom": "2.5.4",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^7.0.0",
    "sass": "1.49.9",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.2",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "sortablejs": "^1.10.2",
    "stacktrace-js": "^2.0.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.8",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "1.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.14",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "10.3.1",
    "@nrwl/jest": "10.3.1",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "10.3.1",
    "@phenomnomnominal/angular-lazy-routes-fix": "^0.1.5",
    "@types/bingmaps": "0.0.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.12",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.161",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.24.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.24.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "cypress": "^4.12.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-iconfont": "^10.0.3",
    "gulp-iconfont-css": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-svg-sprite": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-ttf-svg": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-ttf2eot": "^1.1.2",
    "gulp-ttf2woff": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-ttf2woff2": "^3.0.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.2",
    "jest": "26.4.2",
    "jest-date-mock": "^1.0.8",
    "jest-junit": "^12.0.0",
    "jest-mock-console": "^1.0.1",
    "jest-mock-extended": "^1.0.10",
    "jest-preset-angular": "8.3.1",
    "karma": "^5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.2.13",
    "ng-openapi-gen": "^0.12.1",
    "nswag": "^13.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.1",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "26.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "jest-junit": {
    "outputDirectory": "dist"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with **yarn** ?

As far as I know, npm is more sensitive to circular dependencies;which could be your problem. Maybe using **yarn** can be a quicker way to solve this problem.

Can you provide an example of **package.json** for tests?

Comment: Hi @porzio I have added the package.json. npm is the default package manager, I dont have yarn nor I want to use it

Comment: I tried on my side and succeeded to deploy your package.json with npm, the issue is with the post install script but I do not have the ./decorate-angular-cli.js file, my node version is v19.4.0 which node version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error once in my code "Dependency does not match".

What I did :

```
npm ls
```

which lists all the installed packages with their dependencies (and also their versions) in a tree-structure (dependency tree).

There you can see which version of a dependency X is needed, and you can also find the best dependency that works.

If not, you can try to install various dependencies simultaneously see which one works.